# (How) Can I change my Multisite Network to use a different blog as Primary?

Tags: multisite, site-url

Here's my basic setup:

```
http://my.domain.com/            - The "primary blog" or "Network"
http://my.domain.com/blogone/    - A sub-site or "blog"
http://my.domain.com/blogtwo/    - Same, obviously
```

What I'd like to do is create a new blog called "/network" -- and use that as my Network site instead of the root URL, so that I can use the "/" as just another sub-blog, basically.

I'm sure it's not as simple as changing `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` from `1` to `4`, or changing the path of the blog_id=1 record to "/network". And my guess is there are some severe implications in doing this. What would actually be involved?

Is it even possible? Has it been done before (successfully)?

Answer (score 2):

Change your blog IDs in the wp-config.php file

```
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

That means Site ID 1 is the main site. IF you change that, another site will be the main site.
You have to change your blog URLs around so it knows sub.mysite is now mysite. You'll probably have to do that in teh DB directly.