# Is it possible to put a site other than #1 as a Multisite top-level domain?

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping

Assuming a WordPress network with subdomains:

```
[blog ID #1] http://mysite.com 
[blog ID #2] http://site1.mysite.com 
[blog ID #3] http://site2.mysite.com
```

Is it possible to move one of the subsites to the home site URL?  Result:

```
[blog ID #1] (inaccessible or I don't care)
[blog ID #2] http://mysite.com
[blog ID #3] http://site2.mysite.com
```

I realize that there's no simple configuration change, and that URLs are often hard-coded in the database, so it's not an easy task.

But I'm wondering if this is possible at all with "Sunrise" site mapping, some plugin, etc?  Another acceptable result would be:

```
[blog ID #1] http://mysite.com
[blog ID #2] http://mynewsite.com
[blog ID #3] http://site2.mynewsite.com
[all further blogs on mynewsite.com as well]
```

ie. all subsites should map to the new domain

Answer (score 0):

I've never changed the main site URL (scenario 1), but I know it's possible:  [three](http://support.wpengine.com/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/) [relevant](http://www.wordpress-website.org/change-primary-domain-wordpress-multisite-network/) [links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54226/12615) found in a quick search.

For the second scenario, although not optimal, the standard procedure applies:

1. install the plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)
2. park the TLD `mynewsite.com` in your Control Panel and point it to the folder of the main site
3. create a sub-site `new.mysite.com` in the Network and use the plugin to map the domain `mynewsite.com` to it
4. enable wildcard subdomains for `mynewsite.com` in Control Panel
5. create a sub-site `new2.mysite.com` and map the sub-domain `site2.mynewsite.com` to it

All the mapping process is well explained in the following tutorials:

- [Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/), by Otto
- [WordPress Multisite Beyond Basics: Essentials and Domain Mapping](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-multisite-beyond-basics-essentials-and-domain-mapping/), at wp.tutsplus.com